# Logstash Mutate Filter to Convert Field type is not working

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a field traceinfo.duration in my webapplog. ES maps it as a string, but i want to change it's field type to integer. My logstash.conf contains following filter section:

```
filter  {
  if "webapp-log" in [tags]  {    
    json    {   source => "message"    }    
    mutate    {
      convert => {"[traceinfo][duration]" => "integer"}    
    }
    mutate    {
       remove_field => ["[beat][hostname]","[beat][name]"]
    }
  }
}
```

I am creating a new index with this configuration to test it. But my field type in kibana is still string for traceinfo.duration field. My logstash version is 5.3.0. Please help

Comment: Do you already have data in the elasticsearch index? If yes, you need to delete the index and start from scratch (or update the ES mapping)

Comment: No i am creating a new index and it's not converting field for that

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
filter  {
  mutate    {
    convert => { "field" => "integer" }    
  }
}
```

field is name of key which type you want to convert to integer.